# Periodic interpolation with scipy sqlrep

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I can't get scipy.interpolate.splrep to work with periodic data points... 
I guess I don't handle the 'per' parameter properly. So far I work with this code :

```
from scipy.interpolate import splrep
import numpy as np
x = np.concatenate((np.linspace(-180, 180, 720),np.linspace(180, -180, 720)))
y = np.concatenate((np.linspace(-180, 180, 720),np.linspace(-180, 180, 720)))
spl = splrep(x, y, per=True)
```

But it doesnt work, raise an 'Error on input data'

Comment: What did you expect? These are invalid datapoints: The do not fulfill: `x, y: The data points defining a curve y = f(x)`.

Comment: Why not ? I don't understand... Can you provide a example of valid data points ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html) states, the data points `x` and `y` need to define a curve y = f(x). That means: For every point in `x` there needs to be **exactly one** point in `y`.

Take e.g. this data of `sin(x)`:
[image: Plot of sin(x) with x in [0,7] with an interpolated spline and a periodic interpolated spline.]

Every point in `x` has exactly one point in `y`, and the 1d splinefit works well.

Now take (something like) your proposed data in comparison:
[image: Plot of the proposed data, not representating a function.]

Every point in `x` appears two times, and, even worse, with two different values in `y`. Therefore, this data is invalid.

Comment: Ok that's very clear thanks. In the end polar coordinates solved my issue.